# Zeros of power series via Newton Polygons

Tags: power-series, p-adic-number-theory, newton-series

I'm having troubles traying to understand the following theorem about the information of the Newton polygon of a power series over a nonarchimedean field and his zeros. The Theorem says:

Let K be a field complete with respect to a valuation (nonarchimedean absolute value) and let $f\in K[\![X]\!]$. Then to each finite side of the Newton polygon of $f$ there corresponds $l$ zeros $\alpha$ (counting multiplicities) of $f$ where $l$ is the length og the horizontal projection of the side. Moreover, if $\lambda$ is the slope of the side, then $\text{ord }\alpha=-\lambda$. Conversly if $\alpha$ is a root then $-\text{ord }\alpha$ is the slope of a (possibly infinite) side.

Here $\text{ord}$ is the additive valuation on $K$.

The proof relies on the factorizacion $f=PQ$, where $P$ is a polynomial having the zeros of $f$ corresponding to the given side, and $Q$ a power series having no one of the zeros of $P$. The proof constructs those elements by ''approximations'' given by Hensel lemma. In order to do that the author says:

It is sufficies to prove the assertion in the following special situation: the Newton polygon of $f$ contains a finite side with extreme vertices $(m,0)$ and $(m+n,0)$.

Then he explains how to do that: we start from a finite side of slope $\lambda$ whose horizontal projection has length $l$. We take a $\beta\in\Omega$ ($\Omega$ is the completion of the algebraic closure of $K$) with $\text{ord }\beta=-\lambda$. Then the series $f(\beta X)$ has a horizontal side of length $l$. Now the series $\delta f(\beta X)$, for suitable $\delta\neq 0$, has a side on the $x$-axis of length $l$.

My question is about the existence of such $\beta$, why does it exist? In general $\lambda$ may be *any real number*, and is not always possible to find such $\beta$. Even in the $p$-adics this is not the case: we always have rational slopes, but I think not necessarily there is and element in $\mathbb{C}_{p}$ with a given valuation. Also, the existence of such $\delta$ is not clear to me, since the vertices (the second coordinate of the vertex: $(i,\text{ord }a_{i})$) could have real coordinates.

Is this argument of the author correct?

Thanks

Comment: Isn't necessarily $\lambda \in \mathbb Q$?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I feel that not always that happens. But I was thinking on this: since the value group $v(K^{\times})$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$ (topologically speaking), this should be dense or discrete, if it is discrete I see how to proceed, but if it is dense, we can "aproximate" to the given $\lambda$ by elements of the value group.

Comment: In my first comment I had assumed $K$ $p$-adic. But as far as I understand it, a finite slope that occurs in a Newton polygon is of the form $\lambda = \dfrac{r-s}{i-j}$ with $r,s \in ord(K)$ and $i\ge j \in \mathbb N$, hence $n\cdot \lambda \in ord(K)$ for some $n \in \mathbb N^+$, hence there exists $\beta$ even in a finite extension of $K$, and certainly in $\Omega$, with $ord(\beta)=\lambda$.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Thank you, I understood the reason